# Dynamically created directive properties not working in ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am uploading image and showing it on the frontend using ionic framework, I am actually working on cordova app.I want to dynamically change the directive values like

```
<ion-content ng-controller="AppDetailCtrl">
        <ion-item collection-repeat="Doc in DocTypes">
            {{Doc.RequiredDocument}}
            <div>
                <img ng-show='imgURI_{{Doc.RequiredDocID}} !== undefined' width="100px" height="150px" ng-src="{{imgURI_1}}">
                <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Upload Picture</button>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
```

It replace the values correctly in the rendered HTML but not working fine. If I write hard coded value then It's work fine. How can I achieve this dynamic behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like this:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="AppDetailCtrl">
    <ion-item collection-repeat="Doc in DocTypes">
        {{Doc.RequiredDocument}}
        <div>
            <img ng-show="this['imgURI_' + Doc.RequiredDocID] !== undefined" width="100px" height="150px" ng-src="{{ 'imgURI_' + Doc.RequiredDocID }}">
            <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Upload Picture</button>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

`this['imgURI_' + Doc.RequiredDocID]` might look a little weird but in fact this is just normal for javascript [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), in your case, a way to refer property of the object (`this` - is a scope object) by variable name (`'imgURI_' + Doc.RequiredDocID`).

Comment: I want to make this ng-src="{{imgURI_1}} dynamic as well.

Comment: How is `imgURI_1`  constructed? I guess in your case you want `ng-src="{{ 'imgURI_' + Doc.RequiredDocID }}"`.

Comment: like ng-src="imgURI_{{Doc.RequiredDocID}} not worked neither ng-src="{{"imgURI_" + Doc.RequiredDocID}}

Comment: `ng-src="{{ 'imgURI_' + Doc.RequiredDocID }}"` should work, this is correct.

Comment: It render like ng-src="imgURI_1" on html.

Comment: Yes, and I assume this is what you need. If not, please explain, how do you want to construct image src.

Comment: I am actually setting the value of ng-src from controller. like $scope.imgURI_1 = imageData; I do have URL in imageData but it not replacing with the imgURI_1 on rendered html. If I change ng-src="{{ 'imgURI_' + Doc.RequiredDocID }}" to ng-src="{{imgURI_1}}" its work fine. in case of dynamic change its not work.